# VBA Macro not accurately inserting VLOOKUP into Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

In the macro I have these lines (and lots more like them, 66 columns in all):

```
Sheets("Amend").Select
           Range("B3").Value = "=INDEX(Data!A3:A100,G2)"
           Range("B4").Value = "=IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE))"

Range("B3").Value = "=INDEX(Data!A3:A100,G2)"
```

is inserted correctly but

```
Range("B4").Value = "=IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE))"
```

is inserted as:

```
Range("B4").Value = "=IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE)=",",VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE))"
```

which no longer functions as a lookup and shows as FALSE.

Any ideas why "","" is being inserted as ","?
Is there another way to say if nothing put nothing else lookup?

In case the Excel/VBA version is the problem, I am using Excel 2010 but the person I'm doing the project for is using 365, so would the macro run OK on 365?
Thank you

Comment: `="""","""",` in the formula is `=""."".` in Excel.

Comment: You need to double the quotes within the formula: `Range("B4").Value = "=IF(VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE)="""","""",VLOOKUP($B$3,Data,2,FALSE))" `

Comment: Note that there is `Range.Formula` which should be used for formulas instead of `Range.Value`.

Comment: Amended macro in line with both suggestions, now works like a dream. Thanks